# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a student who is studying auto encoder with keras.
I used mnist dataset as a input (784 nodes) and I made 8 nodes as a hidden layer.
What I want to do is adjusting the value of the hidden layer arbitrarily.
But when I put the input of shape(8,) which I made arbitrarily in hidden layer,

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (1,)

error occurs.
The matrix I entered is the form of np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]), which is clearly in the form of shape (8,) not (1,0).

Below is the full text of the code.
 Please help. Thanks.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

# size of hidden layer
encoding_dim = 8

# input place holder
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
# "encoded"
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" (lossy reconstruction)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# input -> recomstructed model
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# encoder model
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

from keras.datasets import mnist

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
(x_train, train_labels), (x_test, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))


x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=30,
            batch_size=256,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

# encoding, decodeing
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
# I want to change this as decoded_imgs = decoder.predict([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])


n = 10
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(20, 3))
for i in range(n):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(encoded_imgs[i].reshape(2, 4).T)
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()


plt.figure(num=2, figsize=(20, 3))
for i in range(n):
    # original data plot
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

    # reconstructed data plot
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging your code, I found the shape of **"encoded_imgs"** to be (10000, 8).
The array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` indeed has a shape of `(8,)` but this is just a one-dimensional array while your decoder.predict method expects shape (10000, 8).
If you want to try it out with just zeros, replace it with this instead:

```
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(np.zeros(shape=(10000, 8)))
```